# Cumulative Sun's radiation pressure exerts on Earth's surface

Tags: radiation, earth, sun, radiation-pressure

I have some discrepancies in what is in "Optics" (E. Hecht) and what I calculated, but it's simply formula, so I'm confused. I used:

$$F = \frac{\pi R^2 S}{c}$$

to calculate cumulative force of radiation pressure on Earth surface.
Assuming $S = 1400 $Wm$^{-2}$ and $r=6.4 \times 10^6 $m I have cumulative radiation pressure exerts on Earth surface $F \approx 6 \times 10^{8}$N, where Hecht wrote: "The pressure of solar radiation at the Earth is tiny, but it is still responsible for a substantial planetwide force of roughly 10 tons".

It's 2 order of magnitudes difference. Even if I take into account albedo still 1 stays. Maybe he calculated it in more sophisticated way and say nothing about it, that's my firts guess? Some idea?

Comment: Doesn't albedo _increase_ the force?

Comment: You mean higher albedo higher force? My fault, I think you're right, because by a mechanical analogy,  if albedo is 1 (so perfect reflection) photon will reflect back and change of momentum will be twice as much as in 100% absorption case.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is fine. You could include albedo, but you are correct to order of magnitude. It seems there is a mistake in the book.